# SSRS "B" Parameter change to default after change in "A" parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have SSRS report with several parameters (based on SSAS cube). All parameters has own default values. For example there are 3 parameters.

At first I change 1st and 3rd parameters to another value. After that I change value of the 2nd parameter. But after that the value of the 3rd parameter changes also - to its default. But the first parameter will stay the same. There is some dependency in order - if I change 2nd parameter, the 3rd parameter will reset itself to default.

Is there any chance to avoid this situation? I want keep the value of the 3rd parameter same as I defined.

There is no connection between those parameters

Thank you for your help

Ondra

Answer (score 0):

On Parameter properties, in advance tab select option as to not refresh, check below screenshot

[image]